# How to move the selected item to move to the top of the list

Tags: java

```
List<String> strings; // contains "foo", "bar", "baz", "xyz"
```

and if given an input `"baz"` the function re-arrange(String input) should return the strings

```
"baz", "foo", "bar", "xyz"
```

and if given an input `"bar"` the function re-arrange(String input) should return the strings

```
"bar", "foo", "baz", "xyz"
```

Comment: How do you think you would do this? Post your code that shows what you have attempted to do. Start by reading the List API for methods like "remove", "insert".

Comment: @user339108 you should use LinkedHashMap which uses access order to display most recently used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public static <T> List<T> rearrange(List<T> items, T input) {
  int index = items.indexOf(input);
  List<T> copy;
  if (index >= 0) {
    copy = new ArrayList<T>(items.size());
    copy.add(items.get(index));
    copy.addAll(items.subList(0, index));
    copy.addAll(items.subList(index + 1, items.size()));
  } else {
    return items;
  }
  return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 26):

First, remove the item and then add the item again at position 1.

```
List<String> strings;

List<String> rearrange(String input) {
    strings.remove(input);
    strings.add(0,input);
    return strings;
}
```

Comment: Since you have over 20000 in reputation, i take this comment seriously. Is giving a preciese answer in code to a question like this bad? Would my answer really be better if I removed the code?

Comment: when you first posted your answer it was a duplicate answer. I suggested the solution in my comment and Mike also spoon fed the answer. So your answer was not even required since it added no new information and just clutters the forum. Instead, try to point the poster in the right direction so they can learn the Java language. You do that by forcing them to actually read the API to learn what methods are available. If the poster does not understand the answer they can post a follow up comment. Let people problem solve on their own with a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: This is old, but I disagree with the camickr. Posting answers as answers is valuable. Comments are for discussions, not answers.

Answer (score 9):

```
public static <T> void setTopItem(List<T> t, int position){
    t.add(0, t.remove(position));
}
```

Comment: Even if I understand perfectly your answer, some text would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To move the original item to the top of the original list:

```
public static <T> void rearrange(List<T> items, T input){
    int i = items.indexOf(input);
    if(i>=0){
        items.add(0, items.remove(i));
    }
}
```