# Java LinkedList, Moving multiple elements to the top

Tags: java

I have a `LinkedList<JSONObject>` that I would like to search through and find certain elements and bring them to the front of the list.

My implementation is a server response with a bunch of business's and I need to put certain business's with a specific field at the top of the list. Someone answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748930/java-move-object-to-front-of-linkedlist)

But this only applies to moving one element since the iterator will not point to the right element after and it will break.

What is the correct way to do something very similar to this but for multiple elements. I am having a hard time coming up with a solution and would greatly appreciate the help.  Thank you.

```
Iterator it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Object thing = it.next();
    if (ThisIsTheObjectWeAreLookingFor(thing)) {
        it.remove();
        list.addFirst(thing);
        return thing;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just write a Comparator that knows how to order you elements, and then sort.

Comment: Might this also throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` because you're modifying the list without using the iterator's methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Collections.Sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to accomplish this.  Here is an example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class MoveItemsToTop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<String> items = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" });
        final List<String> thingsImLookingFor = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"two", "four"});

        Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                if (thingsImLookingFor.contains(o1)) {
                    return -1;
                }
                return 0;
            }
        });

        System.out.println(items);
    }
}
```

This program outputs

```
[four, two, one, three, five]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically sorting the elements you have in your list To do this,You can implement the Comparable interface in your JSON Object and implement the compareTo() method.

However if your JSON object already implements the compareTo and you want a separate algo for "bringing items to the front " , try using a Comparator implementation and call Collections.sort() with that comparator

Answer (score 0):

Since the list holds only references rather than actual objects, it may make sense to simply add the elements to a new list and then append the original list to the end.

```
LinkedList headList = new LinkedList();
Iterator it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Object thing = it.next();
    if (ThisIsTheObjectWeAreLookingFor(thing)) {
        it.remove();
        headList.addFirst(it);
    }
}
headList.addAll(list); // add remainder of the original list to the end of the new headlist.
list = headList; // Assign the original list reference to be the new list.
```